# How to give parameters for AWS Lambda functions from an android application?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I worked on chat bot android application using amazon lex, for that i have created lambda functions using java project jar. That java project have handler method it will call my REST API. The Rest API request needs some parameters (like username , email id), so how can i pass that id's from android application at run time?  is it possible in amazon lex?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your attributes via the body of you request in Json format. Then in your lambda function you can use JSON.parse(event.body);  if you are using nodejs. If you are using python or another  language there will be an equivalent method

Comment: How can i give request from android application? is there any api available   for interact with amazon lex?

Comment: If you are using aws lambda to interact with lex you don't need an API for lex but for the lambda function. And yes there is. In your aws console navigate to API gateways or simply use a template.yaml to configure the API for your function, Amazon will then (after your upload of the function) create the API their self

Comment: lambda function call the rest api, the api request needs some parameters from user (android app), how can i achieve this?

Comment: Wich component is calling the lambda function?

Comment: I implement the InteractiveVoiceView in android applicaiton, once the user talked and the interactiveVoiceView call the amazon lex, the lex call the lambda function.